# How to automatically call a function when a new object is created within an object

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, getter-setter

Alright let me explain what I'm trying to do, it feels like a basic problem but seems **very difficult** to solve:
Say I have a regular javascript object:

```
var x = {};
```

Now, when I add ANY new property (let's use `newProp` for now) to object `x`, I would like to **automatically** pass that new property and its value through a function `initializer` of the parent object `x` upon storing it:

```
x.initializer = function(propKey, propValue){
  console.log(propKey, 'IS', propValue);
}

x.newProp = 13;
```

So in this case, I would like to automatically trigger `x.initializer(x.newProp);` when I define `x.newProp` (AND as a bonus, any time I **assign/change its a value**.) But ultimately, I would like this to automatically be done for all new properties added to `x`.

I have attempted doing this through setters/getters, and prototypes, but the intricacies of these methods are not apparent and seem limited.

for example even if I do something like this:

```
function setterFunc(value){
  x.initializer("newProp", value); //the name of the property isn't even dynamic.
}
function getterFunc(value){
  return someValue; //SOMEHOW!
}
Object.defineProperty(x, 'newProp', { get: getterFunc,
                                      set: setterFunc,
                                      configurable: true,
                                      enumerable: true });
```

There are a number of problems/complications with this approach:

1. The value of newProp needs to be stored in another key by nature of
   using get/set.
2. the name of the new property is obscured, only the
   value can be passed to the initializer function (as far as I know).
3. even using the getter function, retrieving the original stored value
   is complicated, and requires some kind of index or something.
4. Somehow implementing this generally for all new properties through
   the prototype of x seems crazy... yeah? I don't even know if that's
   possible.

Any help super appreciated... I'm at a loss! I would clarify if needed.

---

### UPDATE

There were a number of suggestions, but it seems like a complete answer was never fully given. After a few months and some revelations, here are some candidates (though none of them totally optimal):

### Proxy

http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies

Suggested by Rob W, seems to be a close match to the desired functionality. As mentioned, it is not implemented everywhere, and is still part of the harmony draft.

---

### Object.observe();

http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:observe

Also, part of the harmony spec, Observe listens for changes in an object with minimal performance impact (in theory). Also a ways off.

---

### Watch.js

https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS

This cross-browser library monitors properties of an object, but it doesn't seem to monitor the object itself. So it seems like you'd have to assign the object to watch to a property of another object.

Comment: Look into [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)s (don't use it in production, because support is limited at the moment).

Comment: Either you create a function which should be the only entry point for adding new properties to your object, therefore being able to run your logic there, or you drop this rather uncommon requirement.

Comment: You're looking for [Object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) but it only works in FF and it's really slow. Matthias approach may work if you control the object instantiation.

Comment: Thank you @RobW, this is actually reallly close to a possibility, but unfortunately this does need to be fairly reliable in production. But interesting lead!

Comment: @Renan Unfortunately, I need something that uses standard property creation syntax. Using the getter/setter functions (or perhaps Proxies) seem to be the best way.

Comment: @JuanMendes Man, I wish it was that easy!

Answer (score 3):

Problem 2 can be solved by generating a different getter and setter function for each property.

```
function setterFunc(prop) {
  return function(value) {
    x._private[prop] = value;
    x.initializer(prop, value);
  }
}

function getterFunc(prop) {
  return function() {
    return x._private[prop];
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(x, 'newProp', { get: getterFunc('newProp'),
                                      set: setterFunc('newProp'),
                                      configurable: true,
                                      enumerable: true });
```

Comment: Wow, this just gave me a HUGE leap forward! Now I just need to make it "universal" so that the getter and setter are automatically added for each new property, vs having to manually add them for each new property through the Object.defineProperty call. Maybe I can do this by adjusting the prototype of x somehow.

Also, I am so confused about where "value" get's its value in the setterFunc. Seems like that came out of nowhere!

Comment: Each time you call `setterFunc`, it creates and returns a brand new function. When that new function is called, it will assign the first parameter passed to the variable `value`. Does that help you understand where `value` is coming from?

Comment: Yes! It's like magic. Thank you! But the problem is still not resolved just yet, as I need this to be universally, automatically applied to all new properties added to x. I'm fiddling with it :)

Comment: @ArjunMehta People have told you a few times that what you want is not really doable. Proxies will do what you need, but they aren't really well supported by other browsers. This is probably the best workaround that could work for different browsers

Comment: Thanks Juan, if someone write up an answer with proxies, I'll consider that the answer! :)